# Symfony "UnexpectedValueException" launching doctrine:fixture:load

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I had to do a pokemongo api for my studies, and I hate PHP, but I don't want to have 0/20 so ..
I have this error when I launch :

```
php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load

[UnexpectedValueException]                                                           
  Could not determine how to assign last_login to a AppBundle\Entity\User\User object
```

I don't understand .. here is the user.yml :

```
AppBundle\Entity\User\User:
  Matt:
    username: 'Matt'
    email: 'matgmail.com'
    enabled: true
    password: 'trololopokemon'
    last_login: '<dateTimeBetween("-200 days", "now")>'
    level: 1
    xp: 1000
    team: 'red'

  Mika:
      username: 'mickaelTurtle'
      email: 'mickaelTurtle.com'
      enabled: true
      password: 'lifeislife'
      last_login: '<dateTimeBetween("-200 days", "now")>'
      level: 2
      xp: 1200
      team: 'blue'

  Jean:
      username: 'Jean'
      email: 'jean.com'
      enabled: true
      password: 'jeanjean'
      last_login: '<dateTimeBetween("-200 days", "now")>'
      level: 3
      xp: 100
      team: 'yellow'
```

Here is the lines in my user.php :

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="last_login", type="datetime")
 */
protected $lastLogin;
```

Does someone could help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the name of the entity's field not the database column, so try with `lastLogin` instead of `last_login`. As Example:

```
  Matt:
    username: 'Matt'
    email: 'matgmail.com'
    enabled: true
    password: 'trololopokemon'
    lastLogin: '<dateTimeBetween("-200 days", "now")>'
    level: 1
    xp: 1000
    team: 'red'
```

Hope this help